# how to fill an expandable list group items first and then fill children rows of clicked group item in android?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I read all of  my groups and their child data from sqlite db and populate my custom expandable list . i want to load groups data from db and when user click a group item the child rows of the current group item load from db and show in my expandable list.
thanks.

Comment: welcome to SO. Please read how to ask a great question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well what you do is create an adapter whose first level (groups) are loaded (fetched from the DB) from the start. Then inside the adapter's onGroupExpand method you get the array of items for the second level (children).

You might also want to implement that onGroupCollapse the extra child items were unloaded as they won't be used anymore.

Here's an example of these functions.

```
HashMap<Integer, List<String>> children = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    // Add children as an array to our HashMap
    children.put(groupPosition, DBHelper.getChildren(groupPosition));
}

@Override
public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
    super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    if (children.get(groupPosition).size() > 0)
        children.remove(groupPosition);
}
```

The adapter has a global `HashMap` called children that contains the loaded children arrays. If you want to get the children for let's say group that is #5 in the list, then you could call:

```
List<String> myChildren = children.get(4)
```

That is of course if the group is expanded.